# uniformly continuous functions on infinite open interval $(0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Is $\sin x/x$ uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$? Can any one help me proving this?
$d/dx(\sin x/x)$ is not bounded on $(0, \infty)$. How to proceed then?

Comment: It is uniformly continuous on $(0,2)$ because it can be continuously extended to $[0,2]$. It is uniformly continuous on $(1, \infty )$ because in that interval its derivative is bounded. These two facts imply that it is uniformly continuous on the union $(0,2) \cup (1, \infty) = (0, \infty)$. I leave you the details.

Comment: Moreover, its derivative is $1/x^{2} (x\cos(x)-\sin(x))$ which **is** bounded.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative *is* bounded. We have
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}.$$
Now, use that for $x> 0$ 
$$\sin x\leq x-\frac{x^2}{2},\quad\text{and}\quad\cos x\leq 1.$$
This gives
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\sin x}{x}\leq\frac{x-(x-x^2/2)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Now it is easy to show that $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ on $(0,\infty)$ extends continuously to $[0,\infty)$, so $1/2$ is a global bound on $[0,\infty)$. Can you take it from there?